# Laravel get multiple modified attributes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, attributes

Imagine I want to modify "name" attribute in User model like this:

```
public function getmakeAttribute()
{
    return "modified".$this->attributes['name'];
}
```

Please don't care about reason, but imagine I also want to modify far more attributes like: age, gender and etc. should I write `getageAttribute()` and `getGenderAttribute()` separate functions for each attribute? Or maybe there is better way for modifying multiple attributes? Like only one function or something like that.

Comment: Yep, there's no other way as far as I know.

Comment: I don’t think there are “global” mutators and accessors in Laravel for now...  you can of course define these methods on the fly in the boot method of a trait for instance, and delegate them to one “global” method you define...

Comment: I dont know if it helps. But a class have two properties that are called before call any methods. There are __set($name) and __get($name) where the name is the method to call. Maybe you can implement these methods validating if there parameter received is or not an attribute of the model.

Comment: That wouldn't work. Laravel already uses Magic Methods in the Model's class. Overriding this would break a lot of things.